# Why does offline Drive fail to enable for my account?

Tags: google-drive, offline

I'm not able to enable [offline drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en) in either the new or old Drive interface.

In the new interface, I select "Offline" > "Sync..." > "Done", and when I open the dialogue again, my settings have have not changed.

[image]

In the old interface, I select "Enable Offline" and the page never completes loading, and I get stuck in an endless loop of network requests to:

`https://docs.google.com/static/doclist/client/js/2418050222-offline_launcher_i18n_offline_launcher_core.js`

304 response

`https://docs.google.com/offline/optin?json=1`

400 error

[image]

Screencast gif here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/126030141/Share/offline-drive.gif

Comment: Anything that might be getting in the way? Adblocker browser extension? Proxy?

Comment: Just tried again with 0 extensions enabled, all my other chrome and network configurations are standard, and still can't enable, Thanks for the suggestion though, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the user being logged in with multiple accounts (which can be checked by clicking on the user profile picture icon on the top right corner of Google Drive). By being signed in with multiple accounts, Google Drive would be clueless about which account to use when accessing `https://docs.google.com/offline/optin?json=1`.

One simple workaround is to sign out of all accounts and log in with the specific account that you wish to use for Google Drive offline. Please note that this only works for Google Chrome and only one account can have Google Drive offline at any one point (unless using multiple users in Google Chrome).

Note: This is similar to Gmail's Error 400 Bad Request, which has been explained in more detail [here](http://techathlon.com/fix-bad-request-error-400-gmail-google-chrome/).

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Google may have pushed a recent fix however, because I was able to successfully sync offline today while logged in to multiple users.